# Is it possible to calculate the sum of each group in a table without using group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, plsql

I am trying to find out if there is any way to aggregate a sales for each product. I realise I can achieve it either by using group-by clause or by writing a procedure. 
example:

```
       Table name: Details
       Sales  Product
       10      a
       20      a
       4       b
       12      b
       3       b
       5       c
```

Is there a way possible to perform the following query with out using group by query

```
select 
    product, 
    sum(sales) 
from 
    Details 
group by 
    product 
having 
    sum(sales) > 20
```

I realize it is possible using Procedure, could it be done in any other way?

Comment: And the reason you don't want to use `GROUP BY` is ...?

Comment: Why on earth would you _want_ to do this without a `GROUP BY`?  Did you exceed your quota on them for the year? :O

Comment: Just trying to learn sub-queries and co-related query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
SELECT product,
     (SELECT SUM(sales) FROM details x where x.product = a.product) sales
from Details a;
```

(and wrap it into another select to simulate the `HAVING`).

Comment: Could you also use a SUM OVER PARTITION ?

Comment: @user2934433: Could you please explain why you chose this answer? This query can return a different result set from the query in your post (it can have duplicates and it doesn't check for sum > 20).

Comment: @AndriyM: Good point about the duplicates. Please un-accept the answer, I'd like to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use analytic functions to do the sum calculation, and then wrap that with another query to do your filtering.

[See and play with the example here.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/226781/sum-without-group-by)

```
select 
  running_sum,
  OwnerUserId
from (
  select
    id,
    score,
    OwnerUserId,
    sum(score) over (partition by OwnerUserId order by Id) running_sum,
    last_value(id) over (partition by OwnerUserId order by OwnerUserId) last_id
  from
    Posts
  where
  OwnerUserId in (2934433, 10583)
) inner_q
where inner_q.id = inner_q.last_id
--and running_sum > 20;
```

We keep a running sum going on the partition of the owner (product), and we tally up the last id for the same window, which is the ID we'll use to get the total sum. Wrap it all up with another query to make sure you get the "last id", take the sum, and then do any filtering you want on the result.

This is an extremely round-about way to avoid using GROUP BY though.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want nested select statements (run slower), use CASE:

```
select 
    sum(case 
            when c.qty > 20 
            then c.qty 
            else 0 
        end) as mySum
from Sales.CustOrders c
```

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but your solution does a count, not a sum, of the rows where qty is greater than 20.

Comment: Darn, you are right. I didn't even think of that. My bad. I changed the "then 1" to "then c.qty". Now it's not a count, it's a sum. :)

Comment: Let me offer a little more feedback. You're not showing the product alongside the sum. And you're not filtering the aggregated sum for `> 20`, you're filtering out any `qty` that isn't already greater than 20 pre-aggregation.

Comment: @JoshSmeaton Yeah, I now agree that my solution is useless here. Thanks for the feedback. If I would have kept the Product in mind I would have saw my mistake. Live and learn :)